# React Native assembleRelease does not work for version 0.59.10

Tags: gradle, react-native

When I try to make a release build in my project, I get the following error.
This happens both when I use android studio and using `./gradlew assembleRelease`

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/<path>/ mobile/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle.map''
```

It works, however, if I do the release like this:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.js --reset-cache --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --dev false --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

followed by

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Since the second case works, and the first case does not work, I think that something is weird with the path that `bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` tries to use. It looks for a command (`'command '/<path>/ mobile/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle.map'`) at a location that is empty. Isn't it looking in the wrong dir?

Shouldn't `bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` try to use the location that I had in the second case? (`--bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats probably because :

1. Earlier there were two seperate folders `index.js` for each `android` and `iOS`. So it created two different bundle files like `index.android.js` and `index.iOS.js` file during compilation.
2. Now these two files are merged and rendered using a single file known as `index.js`.

Your command : `react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.js --reset-cache --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --dev false --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` is basically for `index.js` which works because may be there is a `index.js` file but no `index.android.js`.

To make it work please upgrade your react-native-sentry to version `react-native-sentry@0.43.2`. [Please refer here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25482)

Comment: Yeah, you are most likely right. But how can I get assembleRelease to look for the index.js then? I already have ```project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js"
]```

Comment: @Eyeball Please refer to the above answer once again I've edited that and added a link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command you can generate release build

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Using this you don't need to make bundle manually. This command automatically create you bundle and release apk both.

Comment: Thanks, but that workaround works as good as the one I already have. I really want a solution that works by just calling assembleRelease